# iAd and low cost iphone applications

Tags: iphone, iad

Is it possible to sell applications for money *and* add an iAd into it, or must the application be absolutely free for adding iAd?

Comment: I recommend that you follow [the App Stores proposal on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-stores). This question is a possible good fit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no price related technical limitations of iAd.

In theory you can charge a hundred bucks and integrate iAd. That said, users on the iOS platform generally expect a paid app to not include ads. I'd suggest considering a free, ad supported version, and a paid "ad free" version.